# Hanging indent for references by hand

Tags: bibliographies, back-referencing, bibliographystyle

I wrote an article in LaTeX using document class article and the natbib package, together with apacite. However, the publisher has so many requirements which are indiosyncratic that I think the easiest solution is just to write out the bibliography by hand and then remove the LaTeX produced bibliography pages using a PDF editor. I know this sounds quirky but I'm not sophisticated enough to keep modifying the apacite package.

So, I copied and pasted it from the original REFERENCES list and then pasted it as plain text. Perfect, right? Nope. The trouble is, the second line of the text doesn't indent automatically and the first one does. In other words, I want to manually obtain outputs like this:

[image]

Is there a technique or tool to help me achieve this formatting, but without messing up my perfectly organized text-internal citations?

Comment: How much do you know about the `thebibliography` environment and the `\bibitem` macro?

Comment: Biblatex is easier to customise/patch  than a bibtex style, as it uses a latex syntax, and there is a `bibtatex-apa` package.

Comment: You mention "perfectly organized text-internal citations". Please tell us how they're organized and what they're supposed to look like.

Comment: @Mico I'm afraid I don't know much about either, alas. Document-internally, I just use "\cite" and everything appears perfectly. The references look fine to me, but the publish requests a handful of changes and won't accept just a .bib file.

Comment: @Teusz - And what does "everything appears perfectlty" entail? E.g., are the citation call-outs formatted according to numeric or author-year style? If it's author-year style, are call-outs to pieces with two authors formatted as "Smith and Miller (2002)" or as "Smith & Miller (2002)"? How are citation call-outs to pieces with three or more authors formatted?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `\hangindent` with `\noindent`.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\mybibitem{%
  \vskip\baselineskip% % space above
  \noindent%           % suppress regular indent
  \hangindent=1.5em%   % indent same amount as `quotation` environment
}
\begin{document}
\mybibitem Ahmad, S. \& Tresp, V. (1993), Some solutions to the missing feature problem in vision ...
\mybibitem Berthold, M. R. (1994), A time delay radial basis function for phenome recognition ...
\end{document}
```

#### Output

[image: output]

.

| **Aside**: *Why is the publisher asking you to format references? If you supply a bib file, the rest is their job.*

Comment: Totally agree with your aside, but in this case they don't accept LaTeX but default and made v clear they won't offer any support. And by the way, this is OUP!

Comment: Damn. When I compile I get two error messages: 1) Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment. \bibitem A; 2) Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...and\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers

Comment: Did you compile the MWE, or this solution in your existing doc? I don't get errors in the MWE. Sounds like you still have `natbib` loaded. Can you remove it (are you doing *all* references by hand) ?   Alternatively, you can probably rename the `\bibitem` command above something else, since this is already used by `natbib`. I will edit the solution to rename it.